# How to protect SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

We have an application that relies on some pretty interesting and complex MS SQL stored procedures. Now we want to use the database with those procedures in a shared environment. Is there a way to secure/encrypt/whatever so that the contents of those stored procs cannot be read (copied) by the server administrator?

Comment: You don't trust the admin of the server with the code?  If it's a shared environment you shouldn't be putting sensitive info into the text of stored procs, it should be in your application code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a sysadmin can always get the text of a stored procedure.

Comment: Okay, i guess i was hoping for something that turns out to be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a procedure `WITH ENCRYPTION` but this only protects you from casual prying (it's not really encryption in the strictest sense, more like obfuscation), since there are many resources online that will show you how to decrypt.

If you have important business logic, put it into CLR. That will protect you from some of the prying, but a determined person will still find a way to decompile your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can obfuscate the text with the WITH ENCRYPTION clause but this isn't true encryption. You could also go the CLR route which essentially calls a DLL but I think this could have performance implications.

I dont think you should give sa access to anyone you don't trust enough to view stored procedure code, and if your code is really so top-secret I wonder why you're even using a shared hosting environment in the first place?

If you can't get out of the shared environment, at least try and get your own instance which only you have sa access to.